# Order email does not translate when I choose check / money order as payment method

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have:

- A **Magento 2** shop (translated to dutch)
- Using a Magento extension/module (Multisafepay) to use **iDeal** payment platform
- Next to this, I'm using a Magento 2 native payment method **Check / Money Order**.

When I choose iDeal as payment method Magento sends out the order confirmation in dutch (this is correct).
But, when I choose Check / Money Order the shop sends out an English confirmation email. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You can add email template in dutch 
for creating email template you can follow bellow path:
**admin>>marketing>>email template**

here you can add you custom email templates.

After that go to following path:

**admin>>configuration>>sales>>sales email**

here you need to change the template of ***New Order Confirmation Template*** to custom created email template.You will get the list of custom created template you can select whichever you want.

Comment: I've already done all this. The email translates to Dutch when I choose iDeal (extension) as payment method (used nl_NL.csv for that). But... when I choose the native Magento 2 payment method, **Check / Money Order**, the order confirmation is sent in the English language.

Comment: You change the store view ?

Comment: select store view on left top side to dutch and follow the things

Comment: Yes the templates are set correctly so far. It does work most of the time. It only doesn't work when I choose the **Check / Money Order** payment method.

Comment: I think it's a bug...